# MVC5 - How to validate compound checks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am working on a MVC Razor project that needs some more complex input validations. We are using ViewModels to remove all access to the data model from the controller without going through a logic layer. What we need to solve is how to do the following types of validations:

User selected date is after another date value:

```
// Read Only for user
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
// Must be after StartDate
public DateTime OccurredAt { get; set; }
```

Sum of user inputs for N (variable) fields do not exceed the value of another field.

```
// Read only for user
public double StartingAmount { get; set; }
// Sum of these fields must be less than starting amount
public double AmountTransfered { get; set; }
public double AmountLosses { get; set; }
public double AmountSampled { get; set; }

// Validation Check
if (StartingAmount - (AmountTransfered + AmountLosses + AmountSampled) > 0)
  isValid = true;
```

I am new to MVC, and most validation things I find on Google are from 2010 and are loaded with JavaScript to do custom implementations.

I am hoping that there are newer mechanisms to perform compound validation using attributes to define what fields are related. I suspect that the solution for both of these will be very similar, just a different set of parameters and data types.

Comment: Do you need client side validation and server side?

Comment: I am OK with just server side for these if it is easier. :) The main thing I am after is using the built in attribute validation (same as Required, MinLength, etc.) as much as possible. I just can't find how to do it with dependent fields.

Comment: You need to create your own validation attributes (although for the first example using the dates, you could look at using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` attribute. [This is a good tutorial](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for creating conditional attributes

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I finally got a chance to check these out, and they both worked like a charm. Thank you for the help. If it was an answer I would have marked it as the correct one. :)