# Validate two depending dates

Tags: asp.net, validation, date, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two date values, that I need to validate. This validaton is compound: One date needs to be sooner than the other (think StartingDate and FinishDate).

How can I validate for this?

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868678/mvc5-how-to-validate-compound-checks), which seems to pose a similar situation, one recomendation is to use [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/). Is this still the best option? Is there other way to validate such task?

My code in the view, if it helps:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span style="font-size:large;">Início&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Inicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" } })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span style="font-size:large;">Fim&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fim, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" } })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
<!--jQuery DateTimePicker-->
        jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'd/m/Y H:i'
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Does this validation need to be done in the view?  Because if this page is being submitted, you can also check for this in the controller and then return an error message if the condition is true.

Comment: The page is being submitted and no, it does not necessarily have to be in the view. Can you show me a vague example of such validation?

Comment: Just so I understand clearly.. all you need is validation to see if endDate is less than startdate?

Comment: Correct, and also show a message informing the user the cause of the error.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute (e.g. a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreateThan]` or you can easily write your own - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) Which is the best option because you get both client and server side validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why a simple JS solution can't help here, so here it is:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>

<p>End Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>

<button id="TestCondition">
    Click Me!
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
});

$(function() {
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
});

$("#TestCondition").click(function(){
    alert($("#datepicker1").val());
    alert($("#datepicker2").val());

    if($("#datepicker2").val() < $("#datepicker1").val()){
        alert("End Date must come after Start Date!");
    } 
});
```

Here is a fiddle for that: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efzhu454/)

**Alternate Solution using Controller in MVC**

Once you submit this page to the controller, you can do a check like so (C#):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult NameOfAction(ViewModel nameOfViewModel)
{
    if(nameofViewModel.FinishDate <= nameofViewModel.StartDate)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("FinishDate", "Finish Date needs to be after the Start Date!");
        return View(nameOfViewModel);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps, or if anything needs to be changed.

Comment: The Alternate solution did the trick, with a little tweak which I will show in  a second when I update the question. The JS solution would probably work, had I twicked it a bit, perhaps. $("#id").val() wont work in my case, probably due to how my date values are formated (dd/MM/yyyy).

Comment: @Lernas glad I could help! Please mark the answer as accepted, so that this question can be seen as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Based on BviLLe_Kid answer, which I accept, here's what I ended up doing:

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (nameofViewModel.FinishDate <= nameofViewModel.StartDate)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error message here");
            return View(nameofViewModel);
        }
        else {
            //code for when validation is OK
        }
    }
```

In the view:

```
<div style="color:red;">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FinishDate)
</div>
```